# removing ssh-dead hosts from array

Tags: bash, shell-script

could someone please explain why "s" and "localhot" are kept on final HOSTLIST?

"s" is there although it was being removed...

```
$ HOSTLIST="localhost sdfsd sdfs s fsdf localhost sdfs fsdf sdf 127.0.0.1"
$ for h in ${HOSTLIST};do { timeout 3 bash -c "</dev/tcp/${h}/22" 2>/dev/null; } || { echo removing $h from HOSTLIST;HOSTLIST=${HOSTLIST[@]/${h}}; };done ; echo final HOSTLIST :: ${HOSTLIST}
removing sdfsd from HOSTLIST
removing sdfs from HOSTLIST
removing s from HOSTLIST
removing fsdf from HOSTLIST
removing sdfs from HOSTLIST
removing fsdf from HOSTLIST
removing sdf from HOSTLIST
final HOSTLIST :: localhot s localhost 127.0.0.1
$
$ telnet s 22
telnet: s: Name or service not known
s: Host name lookup failure
$ telnet localhot 22
telnet: localhot: Name or service not known
localhot: Host name lookup failure
$
```

Comment: I noticed that you have 15 questions, none with any accepted answers. To help others with similar questions to yours, and to give credit to the people that spend time helping you, do go through your old questions and accept the answers that have helped you solve your issues.  See also ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) in our Help Center.

Answer (score 3):

When removing `s` you remove the first `s` in the string `$HOSTLIST`.  This will likely not be the `s` you want to remove (notice `localhot` in the output).

Better use an array and construct an array of ok hosts,  maybe something like

```
hostlist=( localhost sdfsd sdfs s fsdf localhost sdfs fsdf sdf 127.0.0.1 )

for h in "${hostlist[@]}"; do
    if timeout 3 bash -c "</dev/tcp/$h/22" 2>/dev/null; then
       ok+=( "$h" )
    fi
done

printf 'Ok host: %s\n' "${ok[@]}"
```

Comment: @DonJ Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by iterating over the **indices** of the array (`${!hostlist[@]}`, note the `!`) rather than the **values** (`${hostlist[@]}`), and then using `unset` to delete unwanted array indices.

e.g., based on @Kusalananda's answer:

```
hostlist=( localhost sdfsd sdfs s fsdf localhost sdfs fsdf sdf 127.0.0.1 )

for h in "${!hostlist[@]}"; do
  if ! timeout 3 bash -c "</dev/tcp/${hostlist[$h]}/22" 2>/dev/null; then
   unset hostlist[$h]
  fi
done

printf 'Ok hosts: %s\n' "${hostlist[@]}"
```

or, if you have `netcat` installed, you can use `nc` instead of the bash `/dev/tcp` built-in (should be a little faster than forking `timeout` and `bash` for each host):

```
hostlist=( localhost sdfsd sdfs s fsdf localhost sdfs fsdf sdf 127.0.0.1 )

for h in "${!hostlist[@]}"; do
  if ! nc -w 3 "${hostlist[$h]}" 22 >& /dev/null; then
   unset hostlist[$h]
  fi
done

printf 'Ok hosts: %s\n' "${hostlist[@]}"
```

If you don't need to do anything else inside the `if`/`then` statement, you shorten it even further:

```
hostlist=( localhost sdfsd sdfs s fsdf localhost sdfs fsdf sdf 127.0.0.1 )

for h in "${!hostlist[@]}"; do
  nc -w 3 "${hostlist[$h]}" 22 >& /dev/null || unset hostlist[$h]
done

printf 'Ok hosts: %s\n' "${hostlist[@]}"
```